# Convert SHA Hash Computation in Python to C#

Tags: c#, python, hash, sha1

Can someone please help me convert the following two lines of python to C#.

```
hash = hmac.new(secret, data, digestmod = hashlib.sha1)
key = hash.hexdigest()[:8]
```

The rest looks like this if you're intersted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import hmac
import hashlib


secret = 'mySecret'     
data = 'myData'

hash = hmac.new(secret, data, digestmod = hashlib.sha1)
key = hash.hexdigest()[:8]

print key
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [HMACSHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1.aspx) class to compute the hash:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var secret = "secret";
        var data = "data";
        var hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
        var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hash));
    }
}
```

Comment: And to print the key, I added:            string key = string.Empty;
            foreach (byte b in hash)
            {
                key += b.ToString("X2");
            }
            MessageBox.Show(key);

Comment: Or you could `BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty)`.

Comment: You can add a using statment to the `HMACSHA1` instance like so to dispose of it properly: `using var hmac = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));` (C# 8 or later. In older versions use `using` block). This will ensure that the dispose method is called on the HMACSHA1 instance.