# What's a C# equivalent of hexdigest in Python 3.2?

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, sha1, hashlib

I'm currently working on a project to convert a Python 3.2 program to C#.

In the python program there's a line of code which returns a string object of double length, containing only hexadecimal digits.

The bit of code in the Python program is:

```
if sha1.hexdigest().upper() == hash_string:
    #do whatever
```

I've been trying and failing to find an equivalent in C# of hexdigest from the hashlib in python.

In C# I've already got the SHA1 hash in a byte array but all the methods I've tried to carry out an equivalent of hexdigest have failed to provide a match to the hash_string - which is what the hexdigest of sha1 *should* match.

I'm not sure whether the problem is the method I'm using to emulate hexdigest or the method I use to generate the sha1 hash in the first place - so it'd be brilliant if anyone had a hexdigest method which they *know* works as that'd allow me to eliminate at least one possible cause of the problem.

The method I'm using at the moment in place of hexdigest is:

```
string hexaHash = "";
foreach (byte b in sha1result)
{
    hexaHash += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
}
string result = hexaHash;
```

EDIT: *facepalm* okay, I just worked out what my problem was. When generating the sha1 hash in the python it was doing it from a lower case hex string. In my C# it was an upper case hex string. So I'd guess that the hexdigest equivalent I'm using is fine as it is. Sorry for wasting people's time.

Comment: Always when compare strings which come from external systems ensure both are in UPPERCASE, since case could be changed eventually in external system and code will fail, so always do `localValue.ToUpper() == externalValue.ToUpper()`

Comment: Dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899644/convert-python-to-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the HMACSHA1 class to convert it.

Answer (score 10):

```
var hmac = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
```